# ¿Una página web para visualizar en varios roles de usuario con VAR SESSION? (PHP)

Tags: php

Imaginemos un sitio web con roles (Supervisor, Agente) cada uno con su respectiva página principal (supervisor.php, agente.php) las cuales se sujetan el acceso al uso de la **VAR SESSION**, ahora bien ningún rol puede entrar en otra página de otro rol, pero sin embargo hay una página comun (acerca_sistema.php) a la cuál cualquier rol puede entrar, tengo el siguiente script PHP:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['usuario_ws'])){
        if(($_SESSION['usuario_ws']['id_cargo'] != 1) || ($_SESSION['usuario_ws']['id_cargo'] != 2)){
            header("Location: ../index.php");
        }
    } else {
        header("Location: ../index.php");
    }
?>
```

La **$_SESSION['usuario_ws']** contiene el tipo de rol del usuario (1 = supervisor, 2 = agente), funciona de manera correcta para cada rol, la pregunta es... ¿Cómo le hago para que ambos tenga acceso a **acerca_sistema.php**? la manera del script que les muestro no me está funcionando.

Answer (score 0):

Quito la validación de roles, pero sin embargo se puede decir que *OBLIGO* al usuario a logearse o no podrá visualizar acerca_sistema.php, siemplemente reduje código a un ciclo **FOR** validando si se *SETEO* la **VAR SESSION** con el numero que identifica su tipo de rol:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['usuario_ws'])){
    header("Location: ../index.php");
}
```

De esta manera puede entrar cualquier tipo de rol, siempre y cuando se logue, si no, lo mandara a index.php (pantalla de logueo)

Comment: No entiendo, eso extiende tu pregunta o es la solución a tu pregunta?

Comment: Es la solución que encontre, bueno que se me hizo practica